# WebSphere Portal 8 JNDI lookup outside container

Tags: ejb, jndi, portlet, websphere-portal

I was supposed to deal with task of converting legacy JSR168 portlet app (with JSP for view) to more modern approach and support EJBs, which are used for newer part of our project. As far as I know, JSPs run outside server container, therefore I cannot use @EJB annotations to inject EJB and I need to do a JNDI lookup to manually "inject" EJBs.

The problem is - as I'm not experienced java web developer - that none of my attempts work. I tried different approaches and at this point I'm confused about what I should do.

I'd like to ask you for help and answering following questions:

1. What configuration files (and where) should I put to perform JNDI lookup? Examples would be highly appreciated.
2. EJBs I would use will be in a separate JAR included in WAR - is there any special location they should be in?
3. Is WAR packaging appropriate/sufficient or do I need to package whole app as EAR file?

Answer (score 0):

You can't inject any thing in portlet because portlet specifications JSR-168/286 does not support the DI and CDI. WAS 8 supporting the CDI.

Better way to do this you have to use bean locator.

[Bean-Locator](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/ejb_3_1_beanlocator_when)

[Code](https://kenai.com/projects/javaee-patterns/sources/hg/content/BeanLocator/src/com/abien/patterns/kitchensink/BeanLocator.java?rev=181)